# Remove "File Members"

Tags: doxygen, doxygen-wizard

I use Doxygen 1.8.4. for documenting some code. I configured a doxygen file for my purposes. After running doxygen there's a treeview on the generated index.html which shows the content:

- MainPage
- Files

  - File List
  - File Members

I want to know how to configure the doxygen file in order to remove the "File Members" chapter from the treeview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a layout file (generated by running doxygen -l in terminal).
Then add it to your settings file under the setting LAYOUT_FILE = layoutfile.xml

In the layoutfile edit the line with  `<tab type="globals" visible="no" title="" intro=""/>` and set visible to "no".

More info on what you can do with the layoutfile can be found at http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html